# Negating a Regex capturing group

Tags: java, regex

I am working on a program that checks online if an update is available. The site that I use for update checking gives me a plain-text response that looks like this:

```
filename:foobar0.2.3-dev.zip
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get the version number (`0.2.3-dev`) out of that String I receive without the file name having to be in this format every time, so it should also work for `baz0.2.3-dev.jar` and the like.

I have no idea how I could do this and would greatly appreciate any help.

Kind regards.

@EDIT

With the help of Ben (see his answer below) I figured a way to get this done.

```java
String input = "filename:foobar0.2.3-dev.zip";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?((\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)*).+)\\..*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

if(m.matches()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1)); // This should output 0.2.3-dev
}
```

Comment: How do you check `0.2.3-dev` is actually an update ? If its a old_string != capture_group_1, you don't really need a regex.

Comment: This `.*?((\d+(?:\.\d+)*).+)\..*` will cause problems. If left on its own, will align/consume the very last period, which could be part of a version.

Comment: The bullet-proof version would be `".*((?<![\\d.])\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)*(?!\\.\\d)).*"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just try to match "number.number.number-dev" such as with the following

```
  /(\d+\.\d+\.\d+-dev)/
```

See it in action [here](http://regex101.com/r/vE2jN5/1)

For Java, import java.util.regex.* and try:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+-dev).*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("filename:foobar0.2.3-dev.zip");
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Pattern does not match");
    }
```

And in action [here](http://ideone.com/IjVebj)

Comment: Oh, sorry for not saying that. I need to do this in Java (because my program is written in Java). As far as I know, there's no method allowing me to get a certain sub-string that matches a certain regex.

Comment: The greedy quantifier at the beginning (`.*`) should be a lazy/reluctant quantifier (`.*?`) so that it doesn't consume the first part of the version number.

Comment: I suppose you are right, it would consume multiple digits as it is. I try to avoid lazy as it's slow but this is a good case for it.  Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to capture 1 - 4 version numbers.

```
 # "(\\d+)(?:\\.(\\d+)(?:\\.(\\d+)(?:\\.(\\d+))?)?)?-dev"


 ( \d+ )                    # (1)
 (?:
      \.
      ( \d+ )               # (2)
      (?:
           \.
           ( \d+ )          # (3)
           (?:
                \.
                ( \d+ )     # (4)
           )?
      )?
 )?
 -dev
```

Output

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 15 , len 9 ) 
0.2.3-dev  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 15 , len 1 ) 
0  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 17 , len 1 ) 
2  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 19 , len 1 ) 
3  
 **  Grp 4 -  NULL
```